# Seaborn manually set interval of x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My data:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'y': {0: 0.8285, 1: 0.869, 2: 0.8781, 3: 0.8806, 4: 0.8825, 5: 0.8831},'x': {0: 5764, 1: 22021, 2: 56906, 3: 114157, 4: 289474, 5: 4755584}})
```

My current plot:

```py
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(6,3.5)}, style="white")

ax = sns.lineplot(data=data, x="x", y="y", dashes=False, markersize=8, marker="o")

ax.grid(axis='x', linestyle='dotted')

ax.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=16)
```

[image]

As you can see, the curve is too sharp. Since there  are 5 points from `x=0` to `x=1`, I want to **expand** the interval from `x=0` to `x=1` and **squeeze** the interval from `x=1` to `x=4`. A prefered plot looks like this:

[image]

where the x axis is uneven and I can manually set its interval.

How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you want `ax.set_xscale('log')`?

Comment: @JohanC log scale is not so flexible...

Comment: @namespace-Pt hard to help without getting more details on the logic. If really you want to, you can use arbitrary values as x and change the xticks with whatever labels you want, but that might be a misleading graph… See for example [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/958l9.png), the x position are arbitrarily spaced (which is misleading!)

Comment: @mozway Amazing. Your plot is exactly what I want, the arbitrary x value but with specific  xticks. I didn't come up with this way to plot.

Comment: Whenever you start introducing non-conventional stretching of the axes, interpreting things properly gets quite confusing for casual viewers of the plot.

Comment: I provided an answer below, but seriously use with care and not for cheating!

Comment: @JohanC Good point. The x axis is now unbalanced and the interval is somehow confusing. I'll consider to use the original plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a graph with "fake" x values, you can certainly do this but this is misleading at best, or unethical/fraudulent in some cases (e.g. scientific data).

You can use:

```
import seaborn as sns

# set up fake data
data['fake_x'] = [1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 5, 7]

ax = sns.lineplot(data=data, x="fake_x", y="y", dashes=False, markersize=8, marker="o")

ax.grid(axis='x', linestyle='dotted')
ax.set_xlabel("fake X", fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=16)

# change xticks
ax.set_xticks(data['fake_x'], data['x'])
```

Output:

[image]